# Complex type in Zend Soap

Tags: zend-framework, soap, complextype

I'm trying to port an existing web service wrote with NuSOAP to Zend Framework.

I was able to add a complex type to the service, but I cannot retrieve that value in my function. Here's some code to make you understand better.

The controller:

```
private $_WSDL_URI="http://webservice/?wsdl";

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    if(isset($_GET['wsdl'])) {
        //return the WSDL
        $this->hadleWSDL();
    } else {
        //handle SOAP request
        $this->handleSOAP();
    }
}

private function hadleWSDL() {
    $autodiscover = new Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover('Zend_Soap_Wsdl_Strategy_ArrayOfTypeComplex');
    $autodiscover->setClass('Webservice');
    $autodiscover->handle();
}

private function handleSOAP() {
    $soap = new Zend_Soap_Server($this->_WSDL_URI);
    $soap->setClass('Webservice');
    $soap->handle();
}
```

The Webservice class:

```
/**
 * desc
 *
 * @param Type_Authentication
 * @return Array
 */
public function get_vehicle_type($authentication) {
    var_dump($authentication);
    die();

    return array('test', 'tsest');
}
```

The Type_Authentication class:

```
/** @var string */
public $username;

/** @var string */
public $password;
```

In the code above, $authentication returns

```
object(stdClass)#25 (0) {
}
```

What am I doing wrong?